# outlook(smtp) Return "504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type"

Tags: php, smtp, office365

PHP returns "**504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type**" when sending emails using outlook(SMTP). Is there any other method besides modifying the "**Exchange**" server, because I don't have the authority to "Exchange" server.

```
$this->host     = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
$this->port     = 25;
$this->auth     = true;
$this->user     = 'test001@outlook.com';
$this->pass     = '123456';

function auth()
{
    if (is_resource($this->connection)
            AND $this->send_data('AUTH LOGIN')
            AND substr($error = $this->get_data(), 0, 3) === '334'
            AND $this->send_data(base64_encode($this->user))            // Send username
            AND substr($error = $this->get_data(),0,3) === '334'
            AND $this->send_data(base64_encode($this->pass))            // Send password
            AND substr($error = $this->get_data(),0,3) === '235' )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->errors[] = 'AUTH command failed: ' . trim(substr($error, 3));

        return false;
    }
}

function send_data($data)
{
    if (is_resource($this->connection))
    {
        return fwrite($this->connection, $data . CRLF, strlen($data) + 2);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function get_data()
{
    $return = '';
    $line   = '';

    if (is_resource($this->connection))
    {
        while (strpos($return, CRLF) === false OR $line{3} !== ' ')
        {
            $line    = fgets($this->connection, 512);
            $return .= $line;
        }

        return trim($return);
    }
    else
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty crude smtp library. Use PhpMailer/SwiftMailer. Else investigate per `telnet` which authentication is supported on the target server. Chances are it's not accepting username/password unencrypted via port 25. See also [prior questions…](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+outlook.com%20smtp“504%205.7.4%20Unrecognized%20authentication%20type)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll try.